# Почему не прерывается цикл while?

Tags: c++

Не могу понять что не так, почему не срабатывает сравнение в цикле `while`?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    char word[20];
    int count = 0;
    cout << "<Enter separate letter 'q' in the end of text>\n";
    cout << "Enter the text:\n";
    cin >> word;
    while (word != "q")
    {
        count++;
        cin >> word;
    }
    cout << count << " words in the text.\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Пример ввода: `one two three q`

Должен быть вывод: `3 words in the text.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Напишите, например,

```
while (strcmp(word,"q"))
```

(сравнение строк в стиле С); или

```
while (word != string("q"))
```

Или сделайте `word` не `char[]`, а `string` - для использования оператора `==` для `string`.

А иначе вы сравниваете, *по одному ли адресу* находятся строковый литерал `"q"` и массив `word`. Понятно, что по разным...